# Android GZIP decompress breaks unicode characters at buffer limits

Tags: java, android, unicode, gzip

I decompress received GZIPped data to string. Problem when I have BUFFER_SIZE as 512 it breaks unicode characters at buffer limit points. As a result I get text with question marks. It happens with non latin letters.

`...во и ��ргуме...`

```
public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 512;
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
            string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));
        }
        gis.close();
        is.close();
        return string.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in the algorithm, assuming that the block being read ends (and starts) on a UTF-8 bytes sequence border.

So do it as follows:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) {
        baos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    gis.close();
    is.close();
    return baos.toString("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `GZIPInputStream` into an `InputStreamReader` and read characters instead of bytes. By doing so, you don't have the problem of potentially invalid encodings at the buffer boundaries.